# Apollo GraphQL Explorer sign in to NextAuth

Tags: typescript, graphql, next.js, apollo, next-auth

How do I sign in to NextAuth from the [Apollo GraphQL Explorer](https://studio.apollographql.com/sandbox/explorer)? I can sign in to the regular website through `/api/auth/signin`, but I want to sign in in the GraphQL Explorer to see sessions and stuff.

I tried using the `signIn()` method from `next-auth/react`, but I don't think that works, as it gives me an error saying, "window is not defined".

I have the site hosted at: https://nebulii.vercel.app/

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Oh, I'm not really asking about the code. I'm just wondering whether or not it's possible to sign in to NextAuth through somewhere outside of the main website.